# Android Localhost?

Tags: android, url, localhost, emulation, android-internet

I know this has been asked and answered before, but I use `10.0.2.2` for the emulator. And I heard I must use something else for my real device. Can someone tell me what that is? And can I have them both run off of `1` URL. Instead of having one for the emulator and actual device.

Comment: "Can someone tell me what that is?" -- 127.0.0.1. "And can I have them both run off of 1 URL" -- I have no idea what that means.

Comment: you need to use IP of you PC ... it should work in both cases ...

Comment: When I do `127.0.0.1` I get a connection refused error. My second part of the question is. If I want to be able to use the emulator and my actual device, Is there a way I can use a single IP. Instead of using `10.0.2.2` for my emulator and having to use another one for my device.@CommonsWare

Comment: I use `ifconfig` and get `127.0.0.1` and get `Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8080 refused. In my logcat @Selvin

Comment: does your PC is connected to any network?

Comment: My computer is connected to a network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Android Localhost?

`localhost` of an Android device is `localhost`, 127.0.0.1.

> I use 10.0.2.2 for the emulator

That refers to `localhost` of the computer running the emulator.

> And I heard I must use something else for my real device

You need to use the IP address of the computer, on whatever network that the computer and the device share. You cannot access `localhost` on one machine from another machine, by definition.

Of course, you also need to figure whatever it is that is running on that computer to listen to more than its own `localhost`.

> Is there a way I can use a single IP Instead of using 10.0.2.2 for my emulator and having to use another one for my device

Not really. Moreover, neither of the values that you are thinking of are the right ones for a release build of your app, in all likelihood. There, you will need to use the domain name (or, in a pinch, IP address) of some publicly-visible server that *everyone's* devices can reach.

Comment: Alright, thanks for being super informative. My server is running on `127.0.0.1:8080` and in other words `localhost`. Here is the `BASE_URL` of what I currently have `http://10.0.2.2:8080/wwwroot/api/`. So I do `ifconfig` and get the ip address `127.0.0.1`. When is use that I get a connection refused error in the log cat

Comment: @user3311121: "My server is running on 127.0.0.1:8080" -- there is your problem. Fix that. Have your server listen to `127.0.0.1:8080` *and* `:8080` on an IP address visible from the device.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? So I'd have my server listen to `127.0.0.1:8080`? And `:8080:`? I'm not exactly sure what that means @CommonsWare

Comment: @user3311121: What is the IP address of your computer, other than `localhost`? You claim that it is connected to a network, which means the computer has an IP address to participate on that network. You need to configure your server to listen to **THAT IP ADDRESS** in addition to (or possibly instead of) `localhost`. If you need further assistance in learning how to configure a Web server in this fashion, please visit http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I'll hopefully figure it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Get the ip address by running ipconfig from dos prompt and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the ip address of your computer for a real device.check your ip address and try to connect with it.In my case I came to know this when I was trying to access some webapp from my android device and my web application was on tomcat container on my pc.It worked very well for me.

Comment: @green You need to specify the Ip address of the machine where you have deployed your web app or WebService...and do specify the reason for DOWNVOTE