# Skipped 60 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I am building a login activity. Everything is look fine but after I submit the correct username and password, the app does not go to the next page.

These are th LOGCAT after i run the app:

```
11-12 15:20:37.223    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed     137K, 7% free 3002K/3216K, paused 40ms, total 50ms
11-12 15:20:37.373    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication D/request!﹕ starting
11-12 15:20:37.513    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:37.643    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:37.953    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:38.073    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:38.363    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:38.493    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:38.743    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:38.873    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:38.933    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:39.243    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:39.433    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:39.843    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:40.593    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:40.743    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:41.663    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:42.493    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:42.813    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:42.923    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:43.233    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 126K, 6% free 3390K/3588K, paused 80ms, total 80ms
11-12 15:20:43.243    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:43.693    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:44.263    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:44.563    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:44.803    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8090 refused
11-12 15:20:44.803    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
11-12 15:20:44.803    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-12 15:20:44.813    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-12 15:20:44.813    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-12 15:20:44.813    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-12 15:20:44.813    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-12 15:20:44.863    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:45.173    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-12 15:20:45.173    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.infinidea.loginapplication.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:106)
11-12 15:20:45.183    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.infinidea.loginapplication.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
11-12 15:20:45.183    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.infinidea.loginapplication.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
11-12 15:20:45.183    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-12 15:20:45.223    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-12 15:20:45.223    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-12 15:20:45.233    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-12 15:20:45.233    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-12 15:20:45.233    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-12 15:20:45.233    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8090): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
11-12 15:20:45.243    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
11-12 15:20:45.293    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:45.463    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
11-12 15:20:45.533    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
11-12 15:20:45.563    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
11-12 15:20:45.623    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-12 15:20:45.623    1585-1598/com.infinidea.loginapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 20 more
11-12 15:20:45.823    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-12 15:20:45.913    1585-1585/com.infinidea.loginapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

And this is the source code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private EditText user, pass;
private Button bLogin;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost/xampp/android_api/login.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            // here we have used, switch case, because on login activity you may //also want to show registration button, so if the user is new ! we can go the //registration activity , other than this we could also do this without switch //case.
        default:
            break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // here Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            if(json!=null){
                // checking  log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // success tag for json
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());

                    Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Otheractivity.class);
                    finish();
                    // this finish() method is used to tell android os that we are done with current //activity now! Moving to other activity
                    startActivity(ii);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Once the background process is done we need to  Dismiss the progress dialog asap
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (message != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: your actual error is W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8090 refused  -- are you running on the simulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800939/android-localhost)

Comment: Ya. I am running Emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8090 refused
```

You can't use `localhost://` in the Android simulator to access something on your PC, you need to use the port forwarded ip address `10.0.2.2` instead

Comment: I am using xampp, sowhat is the port forward ip address? tq.

Comment: so i need to write 10.0.2.2/xampp/android_api/login.php ?