# Inflate Exception android java

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater, android-inflate

Can anybody give me a hint why is this thing happening ?

I have removed `volley.jar`(an external jar but this error remains!!)
I am trying to make a `listview` where i fill up data received from `php` server as json.
I am using `Asynctask` functions to make it possible but why is this happening ?

```
01-03 18:30:09.923: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 148K, 10% free 2529K/2808K, paused 217ms, total 223ms
01-03 18:30:09.933: I/dalvikvm-heap(895): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.200MB for 635812-byte allocation
01-03 18:30:10.006: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 9% free 3148K/3432K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
01-03 18:30:10.043: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 3148K/3432K, paused 8ms+6ms, total 40ms
01-03 18:30:10.043: D/dalvikvm(895): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
01-03 18:30:10.063: I/dalvikvm-heap(895): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.675MB for 500416-byte allocation
01-03 18:30:10.123: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 3637K/3924K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
01-03 18:30:10.763: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-03 18:30:10.953: D/gralloc_goldfish(895): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-03 18:30:11.343: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-03 18:30:12.129: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-03 18:30:12.783: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-03 18:30:14.892: I/Choreographer(895): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-03 18:30:14.983: D/dalvikvm(895): GC_CONCURRENT freed 782K, 23% free 3243K/4160K, paused 82ms+128ms, total 395ms
01-03 18:30:15.512: D/AndroidRuntime(895): Shutting down VM
01-03 18:30:15.522: W/dalvikvm(895): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.soc.adater.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:52)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView" on path: /data/app/com.example.soc-2.apk
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-03 18:30:15.837: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  ... 40 more
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Persons Name-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pname"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Username  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pname"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/uname" />

    <!-- Genre -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgcon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/msgcon"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pp"
        android:textColor="@color/msgcon"
        android:textSize="@dimen/msgcon" />

    <!-- Release Year -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/msgtime"
        android:textSize="@dimen/msgtime" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think ,the relative path of your activity in manifest is not correct.please check it..

Comment: Show us the relevant XML file please

Comment: are you trying to draw a lot of images on the screen fast? it may cause the problem if so - try to find a better way, maybe animation or something

Comment: "I have removed volley.jar(an external jar but this error remains!!)" so change `NetworkImageView` to `ImageView`

Comment: @mmlooloo good catch there. Post that as an answer and I'll give it an upvote

Comment: "so change `NetworkImageView` to `ImageView`" - already changed it  @mmlooloo

Comment: No you have not done it because of  `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView`

Comment: @AlexK thanks I think it dose not solve all his problem :-)

Comment: see @mmlooloo xml updated...

Comment: It is in `list_row.xml` change it to `ImageView`

Comment: working fluently homie! @mmlooloo But 1 more question ------- why is that `Skipped 61 frames!  The application....` stuffs shows up ? is there any problem regarding that ?

Comment: I do not know what is happening but look at [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895936/skipped-60-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)    [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948937/skipped-60-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)     [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat) and search you will find more

Answer (score 1):

### **SOLVED**

Fixed by changing

`<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView... />` to `<ImageView.../>`

If someone gets this kinda' error there might be some problem in your `.xml` files so plese do check.