# Android studio isn't communicating to my php script

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I have a 2 java scripts that should go to a php file located on http://localhost/phptesting/Register.php. My script's URL links it, but when I send a register request, nothing happens. Nothing even happens in the logs.

here is my registerrequest:

```
    public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://localhost/phptesting/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

and here is my register activity script:

```
createuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                                CreateUser.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateUser.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();


                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
```

my php script is this;

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost:3306';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'test';

    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,'user',$db_pass,$db_name);
    if($con){
        echo "connection successful";
    }else{
        echo "connection failed";
    }

    $age = $_POST["isAdmin"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss",$username,$password,$isAdmin);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: 3 columns, 3 values, 4 placeholders inside of mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Comment: @aynber do i get rid of "siss" then? or do i somehow gotta add the primary autoincre in there? Also, isAdmin is a boolean, and when i run the code without any input code, it gives me this; Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptesting\Register.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptesting\Register.php on line 19
{"success":true}

Comment: You don't get rid of it, you just change it so that it's passing 3 instead of 4. You probably need `ssi` or `sss`

Comment: so, if im passing username, password, and a boolean isAdmin, it should be issb? for int(autoincrement), string,string, and boolean?

Comment: If $stmt is boolean, it means the prepare failed. You need to check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your connection, your prepare, and your binding.

Comment: No, you only pass in the same number of placeholders as variables. If you're not passing in the auto increment, then don't pass in a placeholder.

Comment: By the way, `b` is for blob, not boolean. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  You would still use i for boolean, since it would pass as a 1 or 0.

Comment: @aynber i changed it to ssi, and did what that guy said to do. Nothing still.

Comment: As I mentioned before, check for mysqli errors. The error you posted says that the prepare failed, and the error will tell you why.

Comment: @aynber i put the if statement "if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
 }" in after the connection test. I still get nothing from anywhere. What would you recommend of a error catcher and where? Where should i even look for an error? logcat? Im sorry, i dont work with databases at all

Comment: The connection seems to be fine, it was the prepare that was failing. Try `if(!$statement) { printf("Prepare failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); }` after your prepare line

Comment: @aynber i put that line you gave me in right after the "mysqli_exe" line and ran it. this came up: "Prepare failed: Table 'test.user' doesn't exist {"success":true}". I have a database called test, and the table inside of it is called cresidentials. So what do i put where to point the php to the script?

Comment: Since it's echoing/printing, you'd need to check the response the android app is receiving. Otherwise, you can log it. Using [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) can send the message to the server error logs instead.

Comment: @aynber thanks, but i just refreshed where the page was located in the browser (ie. localhost/etc....) and it showed me the error at the end. I'd love to move this into a chat, but not enough rep. So,  look at the previous comment please

Comment: Well, that's the problem. You're trying to access a non-existent table. Change "INSERT INTO user" to "INSERT INTO cresidentials" or whatever the actual table name might be.

Comment: Thanks man, but it didn't work still. The error doesn't print anything into the webside of the doc. nothing it in the table after a refresh. And i dont see any errors in the logcat. but at least it says "{"success":true}" in the webdoc

Comment: That's because you're passing that json whether or not it fails. You can use the error checks to return a false value with a message whenever it fails. `if(!$statement) { return json_encode(['status'=>'failed','message'=>mysqli_error($con)]); }` after the prepare, and `if(mysqli_error($statement)) { return json_encode(['status'=>'failed','message'=>mysqli_error($con)]); }` after both the prepare and the execute.

Comment: @aynber i tried that. I dont see anything popping up in android logcat (unless im looking for non-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two errors on this code:

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://localhost/phptesting/Register.php";
```

Android doesn't like `localhost` you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800939/android-localhost).

Best option is to do an `ifconfig` and get your `ip address` and instead of `localhost` put your `ip address` like

> http://192.168.1.158/phptesting/Register.php

Also your localhost should have a port, right? So make sure you add it *just in case* in your `BASE_URL`, so it should look like this

> http://192.168.1.158:8080/phptestig/Register.php

Then the call should work.

Then I see another problem with

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss",$username,$password,$isAdmin);
```

You are passing 4 values to an insert that requires 3.

I recommend you to go step by step, first make sure your api call is registering something (you can use PostMan or ARC to do it) and then go to Android side.

Comment: I did all of that, and changed siss to ssi, but nothing happens still. I even switched to the emulator. Nothing

Comment: i replaced the php code to $isAdmin = $_POST["isAdmin"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
 if ($isAdmin = null){
  $isAdmin = 0;
 }
 if ($username = null){
  $username = "fakename";
 }
 if ($password = null){
  $password = "fakepassword";
 }
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ssi',$username,$password,$isAdmin);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);Just to changed the usernames and passwords and such just so they wouldnt be null. nothing

Comment: by API you mean Apache, php, and phpmyadmin? then yes. they work. But, ive made another question thats a follow up from this. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132404/android-studio-says-volley-noconnectionerror-java-io-eofexception-what-is-this) it has the actual error code in it. youve helped out here, so ill give you the answer for debugging.

Comment: Im gonna take a look on it if ithelped upvote and mark this question as a correct one thanks