# Android studio isn't talking to php scripts and gives no error

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

Previously, I had 3 scripts that needed work, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119208/android-studio-isnt-communicating-to-my-php-script?noredirect=1#comment93133295_53119208). I did what the kind gents told me to do, and changed the siss to ssi (string,string,int(boolean)). I changed the localhost to ip-address:3306. And Android Studio STILL won't send anything to the db. here are the scripts:

create user script

```
createuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                                CreateUser.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateUser.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();


                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
```

register request

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.6.104:3306/phptesting/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

and my php script

```
    <?php
    $db_host = 'localhost:3306';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'test';

    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,'user',$db_pass,$db_name);
    if($con){
        echo "connection successful";
    }
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    $isAdmin = $_POST["isAdmin"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    if ($isAdmin = null){
        $isAdmin = 0;
    }
    if ($username = null){
        $username = "fakename";
    }
    if ($password = null){
        $password = "fakepassword";
    }
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ssi',$username,$password,$isAdmin);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I get no app-crashing error in logcat or run. Is there a filter i need to put on logcat to see the php/mySQL error? Thanks in advance

Comment: Android Studio has a nice debugger. You need to follow the code to where it wants to interact with that PHP and see what happens before and after that. SO is a _terrible_ debugger! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.