# React native android apk installation error

Tags: android, react-native

I install my create signed apk in some other device, it gets installed once only. After I uninstall it and install again the same apk, then it shows error 'app not installed'.

Also, the user login work only on localhost but not on development server/apk.

I have tried cleaning the gradlew every time and regenerating new apk, but nothing works.

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installation fails if you try the same file if it is not an app added to Google Store in Android

The first option is to re-install the APK with the same code under a different name,

or

Your device is protected from harmful apps with Google Play Protection. This is why you must release the check.

1. Open the Google Play Store app Google Play on your Android device.
2. Next to Menu, Play Protect tab the following settings:
3. Disables the scanning feature for security threats on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your computer's ip address instead of using 10.0.2.2 if you are running on local device. PS: the codes are still running native in the end. There is a better explanation here. [explained][1][Android Localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800939/android-localhost)

About the installation failing, I have not experienced. But maybe it's was already published in Google Play as hong described?